# Path can not start with "/" and contain alphabet symbols or numbers Symbol ">" is not allowed

Tags: laravel, cron

Please why is my cpanel rejecting my file path as descibed by Laravel doc.
This is the real path i provided

```
/usr/bin/php /home/u316901886/public_html/app/console schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

This was the error the cpanel throws

> Path can not start with "/" and contain alphabet symbols or numbers
>   Path can not start with "/" and contain alphabet symbols or numbers
>   Symbol ">" is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You are using cpanel, for this you should try with `php-cli` with `artisan`

`php-cli -q /home/u316901886/public_html/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: same problem  > not allowed

Answer (score 0):

You try this one,I hope its help you:

```
* * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/team1/public_html/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: The problem is still the same > not allowed